# For what $m,\ k$ values does this series converge?

Tags: calculus, power-series

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sqrt[m]{n!}\over{\sqrt[k]{(2n!)}}}$

I am inclined to think that factorial type questions are best solved with the ratio test. I was able to reach the following:

> $\frac{a_n+1}{a_n} =...= \frac{\sqrt[m]{n+1}}{\sqrt[k]{(2n+1)(2n+2)}} = \frac{\sqrt[m-k]{n+1}}{\sqrt[k]{2(2n+1)}}  $

How do i find which $k,\ m$ values make the sum converge/diverge?

Comment: What do you mean by $1^\infty$?

Comment: has a syntax error, fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Hint:Use the fact that $$\sum \frac {1}{n^k}$$ converges iff $k>1$  where $k$ is not necessarily integer.

Comment: i know that, but how do i get my series to resemble that?

Comment: You did well to find $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. There, take cases, for the relations between $m,k$.For example, if $m-k>k$ then ...In these cases use the hint that i wrote you in order the limit $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to a<1$. But there are cases that if the limit is $1$ the series may still converge. For these cases try the $m,k$ ,that make the limit be $1$, in the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sqrt[m]{n!}\over{\sqrt[k]{(2n!)}}}$ and see if it converges or not.